# ST_GeomFromGeoJSON error during insert row in codeIgniter and Postgresql

Tags: php, postgresql, codeigniter, postgis

I have the following table in PostgreSQL:
[image]

In codeIgniter I am trying to execute the following SQL statement:

```
INSERT INTO wq3 (name, wkb_geometry)VALUES ('FG - ICAD2 ', ST_GeomFromGeoJSON('{"type":"MultiPolygon","coordinates":[[[[54.4552662,24.2634702],[54.4604161,24.2579927],[54.4809281,24.267148],[54.4937184,24.2770848],[54.5061635,24.284752],[54.5029881,24.297895],[54.5004132,24.30869],[54.4894268,24.3115059],[54.4878819,24.3033709],[54.4542362,24.3025886],[54.4477131,24.3008677],[54.4430783,24.292419],[54.4252255,24.2788061],[54.4269421,24.2712949],[54.4483998,24.2695735],[54.4552662,24.2634702]]]],"crs":{"type":"name","properties":{"name":"EPSG:1"}}}'))
```

By Using this:

```
$this->db->query($sql);
```

But I get the following error:

```
    A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Warning

Message: pg_query(): Query failed: ERROR: function st_geomfromgeojson(unknown) does not exist LINE 2: ', ST_GeomFromGeoJSON('{"type":"MultiPolygon","coordinates":... ^ HINT: No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.

Filename: postgre/postgre_driver.php

Line Number: 242
```

When I am trying to execute the SQL statement using the phppgadmin it is working fine , and I dont know why it is not working fine from the codeIgniter.

Thanks for help.

Comment: Is `EPSG:1`  a valid SRS? I cannot reproduce the error since you're using a pretty old postgresql. But on a newer version, with a valid srs, it should work. Can you try this? https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=702784c8d7ca0d02ab23db5e9dd1fc64

Comment: btw, postgres 9.6 will reach eol pretty soon: https://endoflife.software/applications/databases/postgresql

Comment: Thanks dear Jim for your replay, the SQL statement is working fine in "phppgadmin" with PostgreSQL 9.6.19 , It just did not executed from the framework. do you really think it will work if I upgrade the version to 12?

Comment: You are right , thanks for help Jim, It's worked fine with me with higher version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using a very old version of PostgreSQL, which is btw reaching [`EOL on November, 2021`](https://endoflife.software/applications/databases/postgresql). I strongly recommend you to upgrade your system - currently at version 13!

The geometry and table structure you posted have the SRS `EPSG:1`, which I am not sure is valid at all. Your code should work with a valid SRS, e.g. `EPSG:4326`:

```
CREATE TABLE wq3 (name text, wkb_geometry geometry(multipolygon,4326));
INSERT INTO wq3 (name, wkb_geometry)
VALUES ('FG - ICAD2 ', ST_GeomFromGeoJSON('{"type":"MultiPolygon","coordinates":[[[[54.4552662,24.2634702],[54.4604161,24.2579927],[54.4809281,24.267148],[54.4937184,24.2770848],[54.5061635,24.284752],[54.5029881,24.297895],[54.5004132,24.30869],[54.4894268,24.3115059],[54.4878819,24.3033709],[54.4542362,24.3025886],[54.4477131,24.3008677],[54.4430783,24.292419],[54.4252255,24.2788061],[54.4269421,24.2712949],[54.4483998,24.2695735],[54.4552662,24.2634702]]]],"crs":{"type":"name","properties":{"name":"EPSG:4326"}}}'));
```

Demo: [`db<>fiddle`](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=702784c8d7ca0d02ab23db5e9dd1fc64)